# How to make a QML app appear full screen on android devices

Tags: android, qml, fullscreen

I've got a code which is shown full screen on the *Desktop kit* when run, but only part of it is shown when run by the *Arm7 kit* on Android devices as shown below:

[image]

Here's part of `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.Maximized 
    title: qsTr("The PingPong Game - A QML Game")
    color: "gray"

    Rectangle {
        id: table
        width: window.width / 1.15; height: window.height / 1.15
        x: window.x + 100; y: 10;
        border.width: 10
        border.color: "white"
        color: "royalblue"
         ...
```

I also tried to use `visibility: Window.FullScreen` instead of `visibility: Window.Maximized`, but no changes on the Android device!

What is the problem please? And how to make it cover all the Android device's screen, please?

Comment: Have you tried the `ApplicationWindow` instead of `Window`?

Comment: Yes, I used that too but no success. Instead I used `anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter` rather than `x: window.x + 100;` in the code and it solved the issue. It's rather odd!

Comment: I saw the picture now. Actually it is not odd, you were setting the x 100 pixel away from left of the application window.

Comment: That was the starting point and the program that way was working properly on the Desktop kit too! Removing 100 points mustn't make such a huge impact.